# Why are chokes nonlinear around 0A ? What inductors do not exhibit this behaviour?

Tags: electromagnetism, control, inductance, magnetics

I want to demonstrate that I can control the current in the winding of my single phase motor (a limited angle torquer) with a bandwidth greater than 3kHz. The phase resistance of the motor is 20Ohm, and its inductance 100mH, for a supply voltage of 100V. 
To this effect, I have wired in series a power resistor of 20OHm with one winding of a 190mH common mode choke (Wurth Elektronik 7448050219).

Then I have configured a Copley Controls ACCELNET (motor driver) in Brushed motor mode current control (small signals, 0.1-0.5A) and no feedback, internal frequency generator as control input, and tried out a couple of loop tunings (P only, PI autotune etc.). The bandwidth cannot go any higher than 300Hz, which is quite surprising, but above all the signal gets distorted very rapidly. When inputting a low frequency square wave (10Hz), the following behavior can be observed: there is a dead-time during which the current setpoint increases but the output current stays at zero, until it brutally catches up resulting in some ringing. 
[image]
[image]
Apologies for the crude drawings, my cameraphone battery was dead when I was at the lab.

I am convinced this phenomena is what causes the controller to lose control without saturating, **and I have tried with linear amplifiers such as a Kepco BOP 50M-2 with similar results so this has to come from the inductor.**

It almost seems as if the inductor had the equivalent of "dry friction" - which opposes some resistance to a certain point, then brutally changes the speed with some overshoot. I'm thinking it could come from the non-laminated core, which exhibits some hysteresis? What do you think? And finally, how can I build an inductor which IS linear?

Comment: Why do you think this behavior is caused by your choke and not by your motor controller?

Comment: @ThePhoton's right; Occam's razor: why would a physically very simple system be the source of non-linearity if you have a nonlinear system feeding it?

Comment: That graph looks to me like the controller is outputting a "modified sine wave" (i.e, stepping between 0%, +100%, and -100%).

Comment: There may be some non-linearity from inductance but I would not expect it to take this shape.  Looks like this is a function of your motor controller to me not the choke. Inductors do not normally allow step changes in current.

Comment: Thyristor drive?

Comment: Common mode chokes can't be used as single ended inductors. They will saturate if you try to use one winding as an inductor. It really does need the other winding to cancel the magnetic field.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In my post I do say that linear amplifiers result in the same effect. Also, colleagues of mine claim that they noticed this behaviour on similar inductors and solved it by changing the inductor. How come ?

Comment: The driver is a MOSFET drive, just like the KEPCo amplifier I used, not a thyristor drive (although it was a good idea).

Comment: @Matthew: good point, although there is no saturation issue, only hysteresis around 0A.

Comment: @MisterMystère are you sure the hysteresis isn't caused by massively saturating the core?

Comment: I am not, but how can the core be saturated at 0A current ? How can I make sure ?